# How to construct a Rails view to edit an associated data set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I am developing a Rails app to keep track of product manufacturing runs. Each run has a group of products that are made at varying quantities for each run. I have a model, Run, that has many product_run objects which consist of a parameter 'quantity' and a has_one product. I am having trouble constructing a view to enter all of the quantities for a run. Simply display all products with a box to enter a quantity. Any help on the correct Rails way to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [NestedAttributes ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)
everything that you need should be there.

Active Record Nested Attributes

Nested attributes allow you to save attributes on associated records through the parent. By default nested attribute updating is turned off and you can enable it using the #accepts_nested_attributes_for class method. When you enable nested attributes an attribute writer is defined on the model.

The attribute writer is named after the association, which means that in the following example, two new methods are added to your model:

author_attributes=(attributes) and pages_attributes=(attributes).

```
#app/model/book.rb
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :author
  has_many :pages

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :author, :pages
end
```